# PropertyChangeSupport hangs when it comes from RMI

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding

I have client-server architecture using RMI. On client side JavaFX framework is used for creating GUI. Items are created on server side and are adaptered for javafx binding on client side. These are two classes

```
public class Item implements Serializable{

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport=new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    private Foo foo;

    public void rebuildPropertyChangeSupport(){  
        propertyChangeSupport=new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        Foo pv = this.foo;
        this.foo = foo;
        System.out.println("Point A") //POINT A
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("foo", pv, this.foo);
        System.out.println("Point B") //POINT B
    }

}

public class AdapteredItem {
    private final Item item;

    private ObjectProperty<Foo> fooProperty;

    public AdapteredItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
        try {
            fooProperty=new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder().bean(item).name("foo").build();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AdapteredItem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

If on client side I do

```
Item item=rmiServer.loadItem();
item.setFoo(someFoo);
```

then all the code hangs. I see only on screen `Point A` is printed. `Point B` is never printed. Besides no any exceptions. However, if I do

```
Item item=rmiServer.loadItem();
item.rebuildPropertyChangeSupport();
item.setFoo(someFoo);
```

then everything is working and on screen `Point A` and `Point B` are printed. How to explain it?

Comment: Could there be listeners set on the object in the server? If the `PropertyChangeSupport` holds references to them, I'm not sure how it would behave. It may be trying to send change notifications back to the RMI server...

Comment: @sillyfly No, there certainly no any listeners on server side.

Comment: Some PropertyChangeListener is misbehaving. This has nothing to do with RMI.